# Como criar um filtro de pesquisa para uma String?

Tags: java, filtro

Minha duvida:

Meu objetivo é criar um aplicativo que voce forneça parametros de pesquisa para ele e ele possa apresentar o resultado da pesquisa.

Tipo, tem o aplicativo Akinator, voce forneçe informações para ele e no final ele acerta o personagem que vc estava pensando, kero fazer um sistema parecido mas seguindo outra finalidade.

```
Exemplo:
String[][] table = {{"Ronaldo","32","Atacante","Sao Paulo"},
                    {"Cristiano","25","Meio Campo","Curitiba"},
                    {"Marcos","27","Goleiro","Ponte Preta"};

//Estrutura > String[][] table = {{"Nome do Jogador","Idade","Posicao","Time"}};
```

Ai preciso fazer um filtro de pesquisa que permita que ele ache o "Nome do Jogador" inserindo apenas os valores "Idade", "Posicao" ou "Time"... É possivel?